# lintr how to set to fail when there's annotations?

Tags: r, github-actions

I've set up lintr package with GitHub Actions:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

name: lint

jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@master

      - uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/Library/Application Support/renv
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-renv-${{ hashFiles('**/renv.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-renv-

      - name: Install lintr
        run: install.packages("lintr")
        shell: Rscript {0}

      - name: Lint
        run: lintr::lint_dir(linters = lintr::with_defaults(assignment_linter = NULL, line_length_linter = NULL, spaces_left_parentheses_linter = NULL), pattern = '[.]R$|[.]Rmd')
        shell: Rscript {0}
```

And formatting errors are shown as Annotations:

[image]

But, those annotations doesn't fails PR check which is actually what you want when you lint code.

[image]

I thought of setting an `exit 1` on warnings. Is that the correct approach?

Comment: I'm not familiar with lintr but perhaps the issue here is that it's treating issues as warnings instead of errors. C# devs face a similar situation where the StyleCop linter uses some warnings and doesn't fail the build unless a configuration is changed. Perhaps lintr can be similarly configured to treat all warnings as errors and return an error code.

Comment: I'll give it a try!

Comment: @AlbersonMiranda, did you ever succeed in throwing an error here? I tried replicating the top comment's answer, but I still get annotations, not errors. It doesn't seem like error_on_lint changes anything in my action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to the code that runs lint_dir , you could add `options(error_on_lint=TRUE)` :

```
run: "options(error_on_lint=TRUE); lintr::lint_dir(linters = lintr ..."
```

It might be useful to put your lintr settings into a `.lintr` file in the directory that you run lintr against:

.lintr

```
linters: with_defaults(
    assignment_linter = NULL, line_length_linter = NULL, spaces_left_parentheses_linter = NULL
  )
error_on_lint: TRUE
```

Then the lint_dir code in your GHA would look like:

```
run: lintr::lint_dir(pattern=....)
```